# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : How to get classpath in?

Tags: java, command-line, classpath

So I have this structure

```
project
  -> bin
     ->assignment
         -> Main.class
  -> src
     ->assignment
         -> Main.java
  -> .classpath
  -> .project
```

I have an external JAR file that I added to the classpath. And I can run main from Eclipse. But i try to do it from the command line. And inside the bin folder I tried this:

```
java assignment.Main
```

And this gave me a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. The jar file couldnt be found.
How can I solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share the full error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/uni/ptsd/intmaths/IntMathsImpl
        at assignment.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.uni.ptsd.intmaths.IntMathsImpl
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 1 more

Comment: [Edit] your question and add that information into it.

Answer (score -1):

You should run:
`cd ./bin/assignment && java Main`

Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2jdK8A863q8

Comment: this just gives a: Could not find or load main class Functionality

Comment: @Err404r  You didn't add all the details in your question. You have to add all your JARs which you included in your project to CLASSPATH. But thanks for downvoting anyway 